# knitr unable to load showtext / sysfonts

Tags: r, knitr

I've been using knitr along with the showtext library to produce HTML files that use some Google fonts. It has worked fine until I upgraded R to 3.4. When I knit the document now, I get the following error:

> Error: package 'sysfonts' could not be loaded Execution halted

This is reproducible by knitting:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(showtext)
```
````

It runs fine without the library(showtext).

Then, when I try running it with library(sysfonts) using the same template:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(sysfonts)
```
````

I get this error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'sysfonts': .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sysfonts', details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared object '~/Library/R/3.4/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so': dlopen(~/Library/R/3.4/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib Reference from: ~/Library/R/3.4/library/sysfonts/libs/sysfonts.so Reason: image not found

It seems like an issue with the sysfonts library. However, I can load showtext and sysfonts just fine from the console. So I don't know if this is a sysfonts issue or a knitr issue. I'm running El Capitan 10.6 and again, recently upgraded R to 3.4. I tried downgrading back to 3.3, but still produced the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one R version installed?  I would try printing `R.home()` from your knitr document, and also from the console, and see if you get the same thing.  If it's not that, you could check for differences in `.libPaths()`.

Comment: They're all the same. I still had the old libraries from previous verisons though, so I deleted them. Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, which yet might come useful to others (if working on a Mac):

1) remove all relevant R-packages

```
remove.packages("sysfonts")
remove.packages("showtext")
```

2) install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org)

3) reinstall and load all packages again

```
install.packages("sysfonts")
install.packages("showtext")
```

This solution provided by [tcarnus on GitHub](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/13) solved the issue for me.